# How to unit test without repository pattern in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing

I've been using Unit of Work + Generic Repositories with Entity Framework in MVC for some time now, and I'm looking for a way to unit test action methods in controllers without setting up Repositories.

Here's an example of how I approach things now:

I have a Unit of Work that inherits from IUnitOfWork interface. This Unit of Work basically has a repository for each Entity Framework entity (i.e. Users Repository for Users entity). I also tried a generic repository in my Unit of Work, but I found I lost all the flexibility that Entity Framework offers. I also have a Mock Unit of Work that has a repository for each entity. This Mock Unit of Work is injected in the controllers I test by Ninject.

However, I'm noticing that this Unit of Work is creating a thick layer of abstraction. I'm losing the flexibility of Entity Framework, while also having much more code to maintain. If I do the generic repository route then the Unit of Work code is more manageable, but this stil doesnt' seem like the best approach.

I've read a lot of different perspectives on the Repository Pattern online, such as the Entity Framework already implementing a Unit of Work (dbcontext) and Repositories (dbset), so one could get more out of the Entity Framework without the intermediary Unit of Work layer with generic repositories. Also, generic repositories expose Entity Framework internals and are leaky, so it defeats the purpose of even using generic repositories in a Unit of Work to abstract the data access layer.

Do you all know of a way to unit test without repositories, or a more preferred approach to unit testing controller actions with MVC and Entity Framework?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: IQueryable is not an entity framework internal, it exists in the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: Jasen, I've updated my post to address what I'm trying to test. Thanks!

Comment: Charlie Brown, you're correct. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: I only do integration tests when anything like an EF context is involved in the real code. Mocking this is like creating a parallel universe with different rules. Besides that I do pure unit test with objects I mock for that purpose, but for that I don't need repositories.

Comment: Gert, thanks a lot for your help. Can you explain a little more how you do pure unit tests with objects you mock for that purpose, without needing repositories? Thanks!